# Why I am getting URLGeneration Error in rails minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

My test case:

```
  test 'creates a new post successfully' do
   get new_simulation_path
   assert_template 'simulations/new'
   assert_difference 'Simulation.count', 1 do
   post simulation_path, simulation: @simulation
  end
 end
```

I am getting :

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:      
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches   {:action=>"/simulations/new", :controller=>"simulations"}
        test/controllers/simulations_controller_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:SimulationsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/simulations_controller_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:SimulationsControllerTest>'
```

why this above test cases are failing while I am able to create a new `Simulation` from views (when I run the application). URL are same but it's not working in writing test

Thanks for your help

## Edit

After some suggestion I made this into :

```
test 'creates a new post successfully' do
sign_in @user
get :new
assert_template 'simulations/new'
assert_difference 'Simulation.count', 1 do
  byebug
  post simulation_path, simulation: @simulation
end
```

Difference is now I am getting `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"simulations"}`  in `post simulation_path, simulation: @simulation`

Answer (score 0):

This is looking for the `simulations/new` action.

Try: `get :new` instead of `get new_simulation_path`

EDIT - for the second error with `post` use:

`post :create` instead of `post simulation_path`

Comment: Thanks for your answers but now I am getting the follwing error in ` post simulation_path, simulation: @simulation`
 
For error please check at edit-1 section